Как правильно трактовать условие задачи с точки зрения русского языка?

С трех участков собрали 68 тонн картофеля. С первого участка собрали
2/3, а с третьего — 60% количества картофеля, собранного со второго
участка. Определи, сколько тонн картофеля собрали с каждого участка?

Помогите понять: 2/3 — это от 68 тонн, или 2/3 — от второго участка?
Спасибо.

Дети купили 10 килограмм еды. Маша купила 2 килограмма, а Паша купил 3 штуки картошки. Какие тут правила могут быть? Можно и так и так трактовать. Но вероятнее второй сценарий, поскольку он следует только из второго предложения и для него не требуется дополнительный контекст, заключенный в первом.

По логике с первого участка собрали 2/3 от второго участка , а с третьего — 60% от второго участка.  Ориентация на 2-й участок.
Это можно проверить,  решив задачу.
1-й участок — 2/3 х, 2-й участок — х , 3-й участок — 3/5 х.
2/3 х + х + 3/5 х = 68. х = 30.
Проверка: 20 + 30 + 18 = 68.  Все ОК.

Подскажите , каким правилом русского языка я должна пользоваться, чтобы понять, что 2/3 от 2- го участка , а не 2/3 от целого от 68 тонн ?

Sharon, вы и математику знаете? )

@Динара Меликсетян  Здесь надо говорить не о правилах,  а о грамматике текста. Если бы речь шла об общей сумме (2/3  от 68 тонн), то запись выглядела бы так: С первого участка собрали 2/3 этого количества или общего количества. Здесь же говорится: с первого 2/3, а с третьего 60% от второго участка, то есть это  общий распространитель для двух однородных членов, связанных союзом А.

@Серж, такую запросто. Я же в классе с математическим уклоном училась, а четверка у меня была только по русскому языку, увы. И обратите внимание на риторику: я постоянно говорю о решении задач в правописании, а ведь так вроде бы никто не говорит.

Да,замечал. А я математику не люблю.

Я  считала раньше, что без математики невозможно правильное логическое мышление, которое нужно во всех сферах жизни. Пушкин был счастливым исключением — как известно, у него  во всех задачах  х равнялся 0. А теперь думаю, что логики хуже представляют целостную картину мира,  но любят все разбирать на части. Поэтому лучше  пользоваться как логикой, так и интуицией))

Да,  вы правы, логика и интуиция нужны.
